# Internal Server Error - HTACCESS file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

I have got the following:

```
C:\wamp\www\MyProject
```

and the directory structure looks like so:

```
MyProject
   folder1
   folder2
   index.php
   .htaccess
```

And `htaccess` file contains:

```
# Turn on mod_rewrite handling
RewriteEngine On
# Allows for three wildcards: page, action and id
RewriteRule (.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$
index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3
```

Whenever I try to reach `http:\\127.0.0.1/MyProject/testpage/testaction/testid` I get the following error:

> ```
> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was 
> unable tocomplete your request.
> ```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As always when having problems with rewriting (which you suspect): turn on rewrite logging! Check the excellent apache documentation, look into the docs for mod_rewrite and find the commands 'RewriteLog' and 'RewriteLogLevel'. Debugging without is like feeling your way in the dark. Why not use the light switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error. RewriteRule needs to be in single line.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /MyProject/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Allows for one wildcard: page
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

# Allows for two wildcards: page, action
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]

# Allows for three wildcards: page, action and id
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ok. I have put it on single line and it's working now. But whenever I try `http://127.0.0.1/MyProject/asdf/jkl` It says `Requested URL was not found on this server`. What I have in my `index.php` file is simply a `vardump($_GET)`

Comment: If .htaccess is `/MyProject/` then see updated code. And it will work with `http://127.0.0.1/MyProject/asdf/jkl/xyz` (3 slashes after `/MyProject/`)

Comment: It works but only if I always provide `page`, `action` and `id`. What if I want to make only the `page` compulsory?

Comment: Sorry but, it isn't working at all now. I can just open `http://127.0.0.1/MyProject`